# jQuery "hand tool" emulation for images (just point me in the right direction)

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, web

I've been Google searching and I can not find what I'm looking for.  I do not really know exactly what this would be called so I'll do my best to describe it.  I am looking for a way to emulate the "hand tool" in various image editors.  I would like to center a large image (say 1024x1024) inside of a div that is 500x500.  The user is then able to "grab" the image with the hand tool and scroll around it (think Google maps but with one large image).  Does anyone know of a tutorial or plugin that would assist me.

Comment: I think it's usually called the "pan" tool in image editors, and on the web [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) does something similar.

Comment: I'm fascinated by the close votes to this question, (currently) 'too localized' and 'not constructive'? Really? Seems quite useful to me, and, given that it's a technique that seems to be used quite a lot, it doesn't seem to meet the 'too localized' requirement either.

Comment: And the question is even formulated in a way that's bound to be found by people searching on the internet for the logic and/or implementation samples of this kind of thing. Not one to be closed, imo too.

Answer (score 2):

Hints you can use:

1. The outer `DIV` or the view port needs to have `position: relative;` and `overflow: hidden;`
2. The inner `IMG` (the one you want to drag and move with the mouse) needs to have `position: absolute;`
3. The moving/panning logic goes like:

   - When user presses the mouse down on your IMG - set a flag indicating that a move is in progress
   - When user moves the mouse over the document - if the moving-flag is set, update the position of the IMG (by changing is style.left and style.top properties) as per the x and y coordinates you get form the event object received in the callback
   - When user depresses or leaves the mouse button - set the moving-flag to false

Here's a very **buggy** fiddle, you can use as a *start*: http://jsfiddle.net/SPXmB/1/

Comment: FYI, if you use jQueryUI, you can shorten this whole process up using [.draggable()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). All that's needed in your fiddle is to remove the `position: absolute` from the img and ONE line of JavaScript: `$('div img').draggable();`

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to explain the logic behind how something like this works. using draggable makes it not just easier but also way safer since it has been tried and tedted acrss all browsers.